# Disable Lazy-Load Entity Framework Navigation Properties

Tags: multithreading, entity-framework, lazy-loading

**Question**

Is there any way to make it so that an entity returned from a DbContext query returns null (or some other specific value) when you try to access a navigation property that you did not specificly .Include()? For example:

```
var parents = dbContext.People.Where(p => p.Children.Any()).Include("Children").ToList();
//Assert all parents have children...
Assert.IsTrue(parents[0].Children.Any());
```

And...

```
var parents = dbContext.People.Where(p => p.Children.Any()).ToList();
//Assert all children collections are null... NOT LAZY LOADED
Assert.IsTrue(parents[0].Children == null);
```

To be clear, I do not want the property to be Eager-Loaded. I don't want it to be loaded at all. I've tried Detaching the entity from the context, but this doesn't help.

**Background**

The reason I am trying to do this is because i need to access the entity object on a diffrent thread than the one the DbContext was created on. Because of this, I do NOT want the navigation property to be set to some defered excution linq statement. The problem is that since I cannot access DbContext to check if a navigation property is loaded or not (due to it not being thread safe) I have no way of knowing if I need to create a new DbContext on the current thread to retrieve the missing data. This is the same problem that I was trying to solve with [How to tell if a Navigation Property is loaded without DbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511597/how-to-tell-if-a-navigation-property-is-loaded-without-dbcontext)

**Update**

Setting the DbContext's Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled property to false prevents the linq from getting auto-wired up, but for navigation properties that are collections this results in a empty collection rather than null.

To solve the collection based problem, I Modified my T4 template to generate an empty default constructor rather than one that set each ICollection equal to an empty HashSet.

Comment: try .AsNoTracking().

Comment: AsNoTracking() prevents the context from caching the entity, but accessing the navigation property still causes to to try to query the context it was created from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable / disable lazy-loading by setting the `Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled` property of your `DbContext`

```
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
var parents = dbContext.People.Where(p => p.Children.Any()).ToList();
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. I did also need to update my T4 template to not set the collection-based navigation properties to an empty collection.